# Add / Remove Tabs Dynamically in Bootstrap - Make created tab active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Here is the snippet to dynamically add / remove bootstrap tabs. Everything works fine, but I would like newly created tab to be active and in focus rather than the tab used to dynamically add a tab.

This is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/F33Av/4/

And this is code in question:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#contact_01" data-toggle="tab">Joe Smith</a><span>x</span></li>
        <li><a href="#contact_02" data-toggle="tab">Molly Lewis</a><span>x</span> </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="add-contact" data-toggle="tab">+ Add Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact_01">Contact Form: Joe Smith</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="contact_02">Contact Form: Molly Lewis</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
    })
    .on("click", "span", function () {
        var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
        $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
    });

    $('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_'+id+'">New Tab</a><span>x</span></li>');         
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_'+id+'">Contact Form: New Contact '+id+'</div>');
});
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
    position:relative;    
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs > li > span {
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 8px;
    color: red;
}

.nav-tabs > li:hover > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please check this link http://junaidqadir.com/dynamically-add-remove-and-re-number-tabs-in-twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score 33):

Here is a solution:

### [**See JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/F33Av/22/)

1. The `tab('show')` is still being called when the "Add Contact" navlink is clicked. Even though the show tab function is called, no tab content is being displayed because it has no existing contents linked to it. What I did is to add a condition to stop activating that tab.

   ```
   $(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('add-contact')) {
            $(this).tab('show');
        }
   })
   ```
2. I also removed the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute to the "Add Contact" navlink. For some reason, it activates the "Add Contact" tab if it's there.

   ```
   <li><a href="#" class="add-contact">+ Add Contact</a></li>
   ```
3. Upon adding a new tab, trigger the `click` of the new tab so that the `tab('show')` function will be called. (*see 1*)

   ```
   $('.add-contact').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
        var tabId = 'contact_' + id;
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">New Tab</a> <span>x</span></li>');
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">Contact Form: New Contact ' + id + '</div>');

        // add this
        $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
   });
   ```

Comment: I saw the demo and tried removing tabs, it does remove the tab. However, unable to understand how it is removing corresponding DIV from tab-content !? Could you enlighten ?

Comment: @MilindThakkar hi, the removal of the tab was from the OP's question. in the JSFiddle it's in lines 7-12. After the content has been removed, we `'click'` on the first tab.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution I found:

JavaScript:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
    var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size()+1;

    // create the tab
    $('<li><a href="#tab'+nextTab+'" data-toggle="tab">Tab '+nextTab+'</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

    // create the tab content
    $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab'+nextTab+'">tab' +nextTab+' content</div>').appendTo('.tab-content');

    // make the new tab active
    $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Bootstrap Dynamic Tabs</h1>
    <div class="well">

        <a href="#" id="btnAdd"><i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"></i>Add Tab</a>
        <br><br>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Hello tab #1 content...</div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <a href="http://www.bootply.com/61679">Edit on Bootply</a>..
</div>
```

Demo and edit at here https://www.bootply.com/61679