# trying to ajax load a php form inside a bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

## Context

I have a bootstrap tabbed nav-bar. The last tab uses khakiout's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815899/add-remove-tabs-dynamically-in-bootstrap-make-created-tab-active#answer-25305979) to dynamically generate new tabs;however I've extended that functionality so that "+tab" contains a drop down. The drop down in turn is generates distinctly different tabs (using data-target). When clicked, a tab is generated and an ajax call is fired to load a php form (defined by the drop down) into that tab.

## The Problem

When the drop down's option is clicked, the tab is generated, but **the form is not loaded in.**

## Attempted Fixes

1. I've tried varying my path variable to accommodate relative or absolute paths. Nothing happens.
2. I've added a callback function that console.logs the request if successful. Nothing is logged.
3. I've wrapped the offending load statement in a try/catch. No error is caught, so the console.log(err) is never run.
4. I also added a console.log(path+form) and console.log(F) before the try block to confirm the variables are instantiated. They are; and F was matched to the correct selection.
5. Using Chrome's debugging tool, I can confirm that .load() is running; though, I can't make sense of what it's doing since most of the logic is in the return statement w/ obfuscated variable names.

## Other Notes

1. Due to how other developers wrote the php form the `<form>` tags exist immediately outside the form.
2. The form must be php because it loads selectors dependent on php variables instantiated with the route.

### Snippet

```js
if (window.location.pathname === "/foo/bar") { //aplication route
  $(document).ready(generalFormReady);
}

function generalFormReady() {
  $("#tabTabs")
    //nav to tab
    .on("click", "a", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(this).hasClass('add-tab')) {
        $(this).tab('show');
      }
    })
    //remove tab
    .on("click", "span", function() {
      var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
      $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
      $(this).parent().remove();
      $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
    });
  $('.add-tab')
    //create tab
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      tabgroup = $("#tabTabs");
      var id = tabgroup.children().length;
      var path = "/path/to/php/includes/";
      var formFile = $(this).data("target") + ".php";
      var title = $(this).text();
      //append tab button
      tabgroup.children().last().before(
        '<li><a href="#leg_' + id + '">' +
        title + ' (id:' + id + ')' +
        '</a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></li>'
      );
      //append tab content
      $('.tab-content').append(
        '<div class="tab-pane" id="leg_' + id + '">' +
        '<form id="Form' + id + '">' +
        "<h1>foo</h1>" +
        '</form>' +
        '</div>'
      );
      F = $("Form" + id);
      try {
        F.load(path + formFile, function(response, status, xhr) {
          console.log(response, status, xhr);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      //nav to new tab
      $('a[href$=' + id + ']').click();
    });
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs>li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs>li>span {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 8px;
  color: red;
}

.nav-tabs>li:hover>span {
  display: inline-block;
}

#legs {
  border-color: #dddddd;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="tabTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li>
    <a id="addTab" href="#" class="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">+ Add tab <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="addTab">
      <li><a href="#" class="add-tab" data-target="phpform1">+ type 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="add-tab" data-target="phpform2">+ type 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="add-tab" data-target="phpform3">+ type 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="add-tab" data-target="phpform4">+ type 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
</div>
```

Comment: What errors are in the console if you hit F12?

Comment: None with level verbose.

Comment: If there are no logs you're not even getting to your try/catch then since they both log? If you add another console.log inside your click event does it fire?

Comment: That's what's weird about it. the try block is running and load is running too. If I debug and crawl through load in the jquery.min, it runs to return and yet nothing is loaded in! I even tried swapping the file with a "foo.html" that's simply an <h1> F00 </h1>. That doesn't render either!

Comment: My gut tells me it's an issue with the URL

Comment: Do you see the request made in the network tab under XHR? Put a console.log right before the try. If you're truly not getting the console logs, it's likely that somehow you aren't running the code you're editing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145742/discussion-between-kareemelashmawy-and-mkaatman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were 2 issues:

## Selector Falure

`F = $("Form" + id);`
should have been
`F = $("#Form" + id);`. The original selector was missing `#` match against ids.
This resulted in the selector grabbing the *wrong form*. Fixing this allows the console.logs to catch the errors.

## Path Failure

The URL passed to `.load()` was incorrect, thus generating 404 errors. Accessing it directly in the browser confirmed what the proper path should've been. My mistake was confusing `localhost/` as my application root, instead of `public_html/`.